# How can I get Metric based on request Params in Actuator Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

Like I have an API /v1/api/location and **country** as params so I need metric based on params /v1/api/location?country=IN , /v1/api/location?country=US

I need Metric based on country param

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.